# How do I access a managed object context in the environment from a view model

Tags: swift, mvvm, core-data, environment-variables

I am trying to access a managed object context that has been placed into the environment from a view model.  Below are 3 code snippets.  1) A data controller class where the persistent store is loaded, 2) Placing the view context into the environment, 3) Attempting to access the view context in the view model.  In the view model the variable moc is nil.
Do not know what I am doing wrong.

```
class DataController: ObservableObject {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Index Funds")
    init() {
        container.loadPersistentStores{ description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Core Data failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    } // end init
}

@main
struct CoreData4App: App {
    @StateObject var dataController: DataController = DataController()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}

class VOOViewModel: ObservableObject {
     @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
```

Comment: Pass it from the view where you use the view model

Comment: Does not work.  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@StateObject private var vooVM: VOOViewModel = VOOViewModel(moc: moc). Xcode complains that I cannot use doc within property initializer

Comment: This is an issue that has been discussed before so search around to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

After some additional research I discovered the solution.  Below are code snippets from 4 sections of the program.  1) The main, 2) the content view 3) the view model and 4) a core data manager class:
I found the solution in the following Youtube video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gGM_Qn3CUfQ

```
@main
struct CoreData4App: App {
    let viewContext = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentStoreContainer.viewContext
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(vooVM: VOOViewModel(moc: viewContext))
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, viewContext)
        } // end window group
    } // end body
}

struct ContentView: View {
    private var vooVM: VOOViewModel
    init(vooVM: VOOViewModel) {
        self.vooVM = vooVM
    }

class VOOViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private (set) var moc: NSManagedObjectContext
    init(moc: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.moc = moc

class CoreDataManager: ObservableObject {
    let persistentStoreContainer: NSPersistentContainer
    static let shared = CoreDataManager()
    init() {
        persistentStoreContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Index Funds")
        persistentStoreContainer.loadPersistentStores{ description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Unable to initialize Core Data \(error)")
            }
        }
    } // end init
}
```